# Temporarily displaying JPanel over a JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am working on a graphical board game program that is based on a main JFrame. The game board itself is derived from JPanel.

I want to be able to display a "victory screen" over the whole window when someone wins. I figured I could extend this idea from a "welcome screen" that I was able to successfully display in the beginning. When this code runs, the welcome screen appears, stays up for 2 seconds, and then goes away, with the game board appearing and ready to play. Hopefully, these basic parts will be enough information on how I have it set up:

```
public class MyGame{     
  public static Board b;                //Board extends JPanel
  public static Window gameWindow;      //Window extends JFrame
  ...
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    ...
    gameWindow = new Window("My Game"); 
    //DisplayScreen extends JPanel
    DisplayScreen intro = new DisplayScreen("welcomeScreen.png"); 
    gameWindow.setSize(960, 570); 
    gameWindow.add(intro); 
    gameWindow.setVisible(true); 
    wait(2); //just a function I wrote 
    ...
    b = new Board("board.png"); 
    ... 
    gameWindow.remove(intro);  
    gameWindow.add(b); 
    gameWindow.repaint(); 
    gameWindow.setVisible(true); 
    ...
  }
  ... 
}
```

Admittedly, it took a lot of trial and error to get this to work. For the life of me, though, I cannot figure out how to temporarily put up the victory screen at some point later in the game. I thought I could do this through a function in the central `MyGame` class (I have tried it in the `Window` class and elsewhere, without success). Something like:

```
public static void VictoryScreen(){
    DisplayScreen victoryScreen = new DisplayScreen("victoryScreen.jpg");   
    victoryScreen.setVisible(true); 
    gameWindow.add(victoryScreen); 
}
```

This, unfortunately, displays nothing. I have tried all manner of `add`, `setVisible`, `validate` , etc., and looked through some other questions, but nothing seems to work. I also tried having the `victoryScreen` declared right alongside the initial welcome screen and setting it non-visible (then just setting visible when I want to display it), but this just puts a gray panel over everything in the very beginning. It seems like when something is constructed, it gets automatically drawn. Having the board as another JPanel layer seems pretty risky as it is, but I know very little about JSwing.

At any rate, I am stumped. Any suggestions on a procedure to make the victory screen (and eventually others) show up as desired?

*EDIT: Here is the way I overrode `paintComponent` for the screen display class:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 

              //works fine for welcome screen
      g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, 960, 540, null); 
      repaint(); 
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: I guess I haven't read into them enough. Seems a bit late now as a Java/Swing beginner with this major project due in the next 24 hours. :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer ..or a `JLayeredPane` or the glass pane or..

Comment: *"project due in the next 24 hours"*  Then stop futzing and display the victory screen in a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: `CardLayout` would save you having to "add" and "remove" each of the screens manually and would do it for you automatically...

Comment: I'm also concerned that you're blocking the EDT, which is actually more likely the source of your problems.  How does `wait(2)` actually work...

Comment: @Thompson: Ah. Good call. Much easier to just pop one of those up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by CardLayout and multiple JPanels.

Another way to do it is by designing a state machine where program states change in one panel.

Honestly, this is a very difficult problem in current state of java, and for demonstrational purposes stick to the first. Personally, I prefer the second option.

Both methods are frustrating and not effective because CardLayout was not designed for game screen changes, whereas making a program that heavily depends on global state is really difficult to reason about...

Answer (score 1):

This may not be best practice but if it's due so soon-

My immediate reaction was to just use setContentPane to replace the contents of the JFrame and then call it again with the gameboard to set it back.

The reason I think the call to .add isn't working the same way that it does for the intro screen is that you're not removing the game board before adding the victory screen, but you do remove the intro before adding the gameboard. Maybe if you remove the game board and then call add put the victory screen in it will work?